# multiple compositions of a function

Tags: functions

How would I go about trying to find a function $f; \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $$f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x)) \neq f(x)$$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. I've tried things like $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and $f(x) = |x|$ and have had no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might start by recognizing that $f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't exist anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind $f$ being pretty dumb, you can construct $f$ to be non-zero, but will collapse to zero upon composition.

For example
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1\text{ if }x=2\\
0\text{ if }x\ne 2
\end{cases}$$
is non-zero, but since $f(x)$ is never $2$, we have $f(f(x))=0$, and hence $f(f(f(x)))=0$.